# How to enable query logger in rom-sql (rom-rb)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-object-mapper, rom-rb

In [rom-sql](https://github.com/rom-rb/rom-sql) I want to enable logging, so that I can see all the sql queries that are produced.

How can I achieve that?

Because it uses sequel underneath, I guest it may be somehow possible through [sequel logger](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html#label-Logging+SQL+statements).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it: [ROM::SQL::Gateway#use_logger](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rom-sql/ROM/SQL/Gateway#use_logger-instance_method)